# How do I find the count of the current post?

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, count

Let's say my custom post type is 'story'.
I've got 20 stories published on my site.
So each post becomes: 'story 1', 'story 2', ... 'story 20'.
Thus, first post is 'story 1', and last post is 'story 20'.
Now when I open one of these custom posts, I want to see the number. Example, if I open the ninth (published) post I want to see it mentions 'story 9'.
I don't want to hardcode it which I can do using ACF plugin. I want that data to be generated dynamically, just like how wordpress dynamically generates post id or slug.

Comment: Fifth or sixth what? Published? Alphabetically? Modified? If a post is unpublished does the count of subsequent posts change? Or do you need the count at the time of first publication? Posts don’t have an inherent “count” without some sort of context.

Comment: published. I just want to know if the current post is the 1st or 2nd or 3rd or 4th or...

Comment: The answer to this is going to change depending on the context, you need to be very very specific. But I suspect that this is an X Y problem, where you didn't ask how to solve your problem, but how to iimplement a solution you've devised. What is the problem that knowing the nth post is meant to solve? Keep in mind what you've asked will require unique answers for every type of archive as well as every custom query. Posts don't store or have an nth position, much like sorting everybody in your workplace by height and appearing 3rd doesn't mean you have a card with the number 3 in your pocket

Comment: Thank you, for the reply. Though you've mentioned it's not possible, I've still edited my question if I failed to make things clear last time.

Comment: @Ash Your question makes sense, although it might be quite hard to do. If you have 20 posts so they are numbered 1-20, it means if you delete number 15, the rest of them will all change number - is that ok with you?

Comment: @mozboz you mean if I delete the 15th published post, story 15 will be missing. But it will still be show story 14 and story 16?

Comment: No, if all you do is number according to the order like in your question, then 16 will become 15, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't an order or numbering of posts like this that is stored in Wordpress.

The database stores things with a 'primary key', which is just a number, but this always stays the same for each post, forever. So if you add lots of posts and remove lots of posts then add some more, the Primary Key for the first 3 posts might be 1,20,100.

If you want to find the 'count' or the 'order' of posts like in your question then you have to choose how you want to sort them and then find the order yourself.

For example, you could use WP_Query to get all your posts ordered by date, and then print them in order giving them numbers 1,2,3,4, and you could also use this list to determine what number in this list any post was.

HTH. Please expand your question if you need more information.

EDIT:

So according to your updated question you need to do something like this. You *could* store this number in a post_meta field and hook into the save post hook to update this if you wanted to - that would be more efficient than running this on every page load.

```
$args = Array(
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'ASC' // oldest first
}

$postsSorted = get_posts($args);

$count = 1;
$postToNumbers = Array();


foreach($postsSorted as $post) {
    $postNumbers[$post->ID] = $count;
    $count++;
}
```

This would give you an array that lets you look up the 'count' for any post ID. So you use this like:

```
$postID = get_the_ID();  // whatever method is relevant to where you are to get the post ID 
echo "The count of this post is " . $postNumbers[$postID] ;
```

You could put this in a function to make it easy to call, or as above you could hook it into the save / delete posts hooks to store the number in post meta and make the number get updated whenever posts are added removed, but you'll need to write the code for that ;-)

Does that help?

Comment: Hi @mozboz just expanded my question. Please take a look.

Comment: @Ash I've added a quick bit of code with how you can achieve this, but it's untested and you'll need to figure out exactly how you want to use it - maybe in a function in functions.php or in a hook as mentioned.

Comment: Thanks! It worked.

Answer (score 0):

Following @mozboz answer, I wrote an "explicit version" of the code (the previous throw me an error). This worked for me, in my single.php footer:

```
$count = 0;
$post_array = Array();

$args = Array(
    'post_type'     => 'post',
    'orderby'       => 'date',
    'order'         => 'DESC',
    'posts_per_page'=> -1
);
$posts_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $posts_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $posts_query->have_posts() ) {
        $posts_query->the_post();
        $post_id = get_the_ID();
        $post_array[] = $post_id;
        $count++;
    }
} 
wp_reset_postdata();

$post_id = get_the_ID();
$position = array_search($post_id, $post_array);

echo $position +1 . '/' . $count;
```